# How to assign thumb or icon to QListView Item while using .model

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a single QListView with three items. This QListView gets populated via its .model's. Without using the model I could go ahead and do something like this:

```
view=QtGui.QListWidget()
item=QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
item.setText('Item Name')
icon=QtGui.QIcon('/Volumes/path/to/file.jpg')
item.setIcon(icon)
view.addItem(item)
```

But with `.model' in use there are no items available (the indexes instead). Please advise.

[image]

```
    import os,sys
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}

    class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
        def __init__(self):
            QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
            self.items=[] 
            self.modelDict={} 
        def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
            return len(self.items)
        def data(self, index, role):
            if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):  return QtCore.QVariant()
            if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:      return self.items[index.row()]
        def addItems(self):
            for key in self.modelDict:
                index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
                self.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
                self.items.append(key)      
            self.endInsertRows()        

    class ListView(QtGui.QListView):
        def __init__(self):
            super(ListView, self).__init__()
            self.model= Model()
            self.model.modelDict=elements
            self.model.addItems()
            self.setModel(self.model)
            self.show()        

    window=ListView()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDIT: Thanks to Jeffrey for a detailed explanation!

---

The code below is revised fully working version of the one posted earlier. Basically we have to supply model with the data requested. The actual icon "assignment" will be handled by the model itself. We only need to make sure the request for icon happens under correct `if Role==x` scope. The icons should be requested/returned in `if DecorationRole` portion of `.data()` method. There are other roles available: `Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.TextAlignmentRole, Qt.TextColorRole, Qt.BackgroundColorRole, Qt.ItemDataRole, Qt.UserRole` and etc)

[image]

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}

icon=QtGui.QIcon('C:\\myIcon.png')

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[] 
        self.modelDict={}       

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):  return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.items[index.row()]
        elif role==QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            return icon

    def addItems(self):
        for key in self.modelDict:
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
            self.items.append(key)      
        self.endInsertRows()        

class ListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListView, self).__init__()
        self.model= Model()
        self.model.modelDict=elements
        self.model.addItems()
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.show()        

window=ListView()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you'll need `Model.data` to be able to return a `QIcon` (or `QPixmap`, if that's more convenient) when the role passed in is [`DecorationRole`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). With this current code, it'll return `None`, which not only doesn't do what you want, is actually invalid. If it doesn't know how to deal with the passed role, it should return an invalid `QVariant` (like you do on the first line of the method). PyQt is probably smart enough to handle `None` properly, though.

Secondly, you already appear to be using the `QModelIndex` correctly. You can just have the icon be another field attached to the model itself that you access similarly. `QListWidgetItem` is simply a convenience class, and there's nothing stopping you from encapsulating all of the data associated with a row in a similar class that you stash on the model (like you're already doing with the `DisplayRole` data) and access via the `QModelIndex.row()`.

Something like this:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if not index.isValid() or not (0 <= index.row() < len(self.items)):
        return QtCore.QVariant()
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return self.items[index.row()]
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
        return self.icons[index.row()]
    return QtCore.QVariant()
```

Although I'd personally recommend having a dict whose values contain both the `DisplayRole` and `DecorationRole` data as fields on a class.

I don't know off-hand if a `QListView` will request the `DecorationRole` from the model by default. You might need to set the [`iconSize`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#iconSize-prop) property on the list view, or similar. These are all the changes you need to make to the model itself, though.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I still don't understand how and where the `index`'s assignment to the icon happens.... in `.addItem()` method?

Comment: How can I assign the icon using `index` (QModelIndex) instead of a "regular" `QListWidgetItem`? What would be a correct syntax?

Comment: You don't assign the icon. The `QListView` queries it from the model. You're currently constructing a model by giving your subclass a list of strings. You can also give it a list of icons that correspond, or have one list like so: `elements = [ {'icon': QIcon(), 'name': 'name' }, ... ]` and using that in the model's items, accessing .icon or .name.

Comment: So I always query `QModelIndex` only to get its `.row()` number so it could be used to get a "real" value from a class `list` variable such as `elements` or `self.allIconsInTheWorld=['c:/GreatIcon.jpg, c:/Another_Terrific_Icong.png']`? Correct?

Comment: So, if request to `self.icons[index.row()]` returns a valid file path to the image (such as .png or .jpg) `model` will take care and assign the image to corresponding `QModelIndex` (I mean `QListView Item`)?

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Model indeed is a quite confusing concept to me. So much is happening "behind of scenes".... "all by itself"